# Microsoft Access - How do I import data to an existing Table and update the data

Tags: sql, ms-access

simple yet, a question I can not find an answer too.

I am currently importing RAW Data from Excel to my ACCESS database.
Every day, this RAW data I receive updates in status.

I have a field/key that never changes for example a Document number. However, fields like "Status" and "quantity" can change based on a given situation.

Is there a way for me import my new file into my existing data and have it update/overwrite data that matches my Document number field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a unique constraint on the fields which will be unique then you can use

```
UPDATE
MyAccessTable A
INNER JOIN MyLinkedExcelTable X
    ON A.document_number = X.document_number
SET A.f1 = X.f1
```

then insert the missing ones using

```
INSERT INTO MyAccessTable (f1, f2, .....)
SELECT f1, f2, ....
FROM MyLinkedExcelTable X
WHERE X.document_number NOT IN (SELECT Document_number FROM MyAccessTable)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! i will add this into the query. you are a life saver~

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer. cheers